# Yii2 ActiveForm issue

Tags: forms, passwords, yii2

I have a update user form with fields such as username, email, password, etc. I need the password field to be empty and to update the users.password field in the MySQL database only when the user has filled in the password field. Is it possible? I use the ActiveForm widget of Yii2.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: And how can I achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is here. If you leave a field empty then it doesn't get updated, simple. If you are experiencing problems, then we're likely to need to see some code so we can help you to pinpoint what your problem is as it's not normally a problem. Useful code to see would be your complete model, relevant controller action and the view being used.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not an Yii2 ActiveForm issue. It can be possible by following some simple steps.

Create two variables in your model, one for storing password, and another is for repeat password field.

```
public $REPEAT_PASSWORD;
public $INIT_PASSWORD;
```

then add afterFind function to set null value to your password field, so it wont be shown to user

```
    public function afterFind()
{
    //reset the password to null because we don't want password to be shown.
    $this->INIT_PASSWORD = $this->PASSWORD;
    $this->PASSWORD = null;

    parent::afterFind();
}
```

and now, write beforeSave function to save user password if user has entered on

```
    public function beforeSave()
{
    // in this case, we will use the old hashed password.
    if(empty($this->PASSWORD) && empty($this->REPEAT_PASSWORD) && !empty($this->INIT_PASSWORD)) {
        $this->PASSWORD=$this->REPEAT_PASSWORD=$this->INIT_PASSWORD;
    }   elseif(!empty($this->PASSWORD) && !empty($this->REPEAT_PASSWORD) && ($this->PASSWORD == $this->REPEAT_PASSWORD))   {
        $this->PASSWORD = md5($this->PASSWORD);
        $this->REPEAT_PASSWORD = md5($this->REPEAT_PASSWORD);
    }

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```